# Optimize dynamic complex layout in ScrollView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have question about optimizing the scrollview. My app has rich UI like **lazada** or **shopee**. This app has a lot of components vertically, each component has a button like **See More** and list data below (data in layout like recyclerview or viewpager or horizontal list...)
Each component has id to get data to call api. I uses `Fragment` with each component so each component can call api and display own UI, I add list of fragments to `LinearLayout`

I have problem about the performance, it's quite lag when the number of components is too much. Because I don't use `recyclerview`, it will show all data and UI for the first time (take much time for first load).

The complex UI likes this

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestion for improving UI is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: i think using a RecyclerView is better choice here. RecyclerView will also load all the visible components, and some more. But will lazy load which are not visible. Why dont try RecyclerView?

Comment: use nestedScrollView with recyclerviews (for horizontal scroll).

Comment: @TouhidulIslam. Because of each component, I use an api to get data, so I use fragment for easy to manage all apis. For example above: with Flash Deal, I use api A ; with RedMart, I use api B. If I use recyclerview. I have to prepare all data (load all apis) before load recyclerview.

Comment: @arjunkn, I am using NestedScrollView, they are the same.

Comment: @RoShanShan then i think recycler view is my next option. Call all apis at once and add item to recyclerview when one api finishes loading and so on, so user don't have to wait to load all apis.

Comment: @arjunkn, I think I will think about this in near future, it affects a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @RoShanShan you can use database, or simple save the json in file format to avoid/reduce api calls. but still you should use RecylerView or something similar